# autolayout scrollview best approach

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints, xib

I don't find a way for create a scrollview with some view inside, I create a xib with some element and some constraint, the I create a controller with scrollview->scrollviewcontent->{v1,v2,v3} bot my v1,v2,v3 seems to be with constraint.
This is my code, where I make the mistake?

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    if (isFirst)
    {
        [self initViews];
        [self initConstraints];
        [self initTutorial];

        isFirst = NO;
    }
}


-(void) initViews
{
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_scrollView setDelegate:self];


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This content view will be the only child view of scrollview
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    _scrollViewContent = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [_scrollViewContent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    // add content view to scrollview now
    [_scrollView addSubview:_scrollViewContent];

    // add scrollview to main view
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

}
-(void) initConstraints
{
    _scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _scrollViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    id views = @{
                 @"_scrollView": _scrollView,
                 @"_scrollViewContent": _scrollViewContent
                 };

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollViewContent]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollViewContent]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}

- (void) initTutorial {

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    int i = 0;
    for (V10Page *page in pagineTutorial)
    {
        V10Widget *widget = [page.page objectForKey:@"description"];

        TutorialPage *tutorial = [[TutorialPage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * [Utils getScreenSize].width, 0,[Utils getScreenSize].width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)
                                                             andText:[widget getValueForDefaultLanguage]
                                                            andImage:nil];
        [_scrollViewContent addSubview:tutorial];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];


        i++;
    }
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (pagineTutorial.count > 0)
    {
        [_scrollViewContent setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width * pagineTutorial.count, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [_scrollView setContentSize:_scrollViewContent.frame.size];
    }

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Many iOS developers have one common problems with using `AutoLayout` with `UIScrollView`. It is usually not that difficult, just few things to keep in mind.

1. Add Scroll View to the main `UIView` and give constraints with respect to `UIView`.
2. Add a content view (`UIView`) inside the `ScrollView` and give top, bottom, left and right constraints w.r.t `ScrollView`. Also add equal width and equal height constraints w.r.t main `UIView`.
3. Set the equal height constraint's priority to low if you need vertical scrolling.
4. Now you can add any contents inside the Content View and add constraints  w.r.t `ContentView`.

You can get detailed info from [`UIScrollView` with `AutoLayout`](https://iosschool.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/uiscrollview-with-autolayout/)